# Laravel pivot model relationship with another table

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

[image]

**Database Explanation:**

- Item has many tiers
- Tier has one type (Size, Option OR Addon)
- type has many-to-many relationship with option
- optionType has many sizes and price

**The Problem:**
In eloquent query I am able to fetch data until option_type, I don't know how to create relationship of option_type pivot model with size model.

**Eloquent Query:**

```
$items = Item::with(['tiers' => function ($query) {
            $query->with(['type' => function($query) {
                $query->with('sizes')
                    ->with('options')
                    ->with('addons');
            }]);
        }])->where('id', 1)->get();
        return $items;
```

**What I want to Achieve:**
I want to eager load option_type with sizes, for every optiontype row i may have size and its price.

**The Problem:**
when i write a query like:

```
$query->with(['options' => function($query) {
    $query->with('sizes);
}])
```

It is basically saying that options have relationship with sizes which is not right, it should be optionType have relationship with size. how to can i get the data so that i would show me for record for each optiontype_id, size_id and price.

**Type Model:**

```
class Type extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'types';

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class);
    }
}
```

**Option Model:**

```
class Option extends Model
{
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Type::class);
    }
}
```

**OptionType Model:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class OptionType extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'option_type';

    public function optiontypesize()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'option_type_size', 'size_id', 'option_type_id');
    }
}
```

**Size Model:**

```
class Size extends Model
{
    public function optiontypesize()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OptionType::class, 'option_type_size', 'size_id', 'option_type_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem myself, I will write the detailed answer here in case if someone ran into same problem in future.

I have modified the database but the concept of problem remains the same.

[image]

**Explanation:**

- items has many tiers
- tiers has one type
- tiers has many options and options has many tiers (bringing the
  option_tier table in scene)
- option_tier has many sizes and sizes has many option_tier (bringing
  the option_tier_price table in scene, with an additional field of
  'price')

**Solutions:**
I am using [AjCastro\EagerLoadPivotRelations\EagerLoadPivotTrait](https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations) for eager loading pivot relations.
The concept is taken from this article https://medium.com/@ajcastro29/laravel-eloquent-eager-load-pivot-relations-dba579f3fd3a
The only difference is i have changed the relationship from `belongTo` to `hasMany` and it works like a charm.

**Tier Model:**

```
use AjCastro\EagerLoadPivotRelations\EagerLoadPivotTrait;

class Tier extends Model
{
    use EagerLoadPivotTrait;
    protected $table = 'tiers';

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class, 'option_tier')
            ->using(OptionTier::class)
            ->withPivot('id');
    }
}
```

**Option Model:**

```
use AjCastro\EagerLoadPivotRelations\EagerLoadPivotTrait;

class Option extends Model
{
    use EagerLoadPivotTrait;

    protected $table = 'options';
    
    public function tiers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tier::class, 'option_tier');
    }
}
```

**OptionTier Model:**

```
use AjCastro\EagerLoadPivotRelations\EagerLoadPivotTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class OptionTier extends Pivot
{
    use EagerLoadPivotTrait;
    
    protected $table = 'option_tier';
    
    public function price()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OptionTierPrice::class, 'option_tier_id');
    }
}
```

**OptionTierPrice Model:**

```
use AjCastro\EagerLoadPivotRelations\EagerLoadPivotTrait;

class OptionTierPrice extends Model
{
    use EagerLoadPivotTrait;
    
    protected $table = 'option_tier_price';
    
    public function size()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Size::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$tiers = Product::with(['tiers' => function($query) {
    $query->with(['type'])
          ->with(['sizes'])
          ->with(['options.pivot.price.size'])
          ->with(['addons.pivot.price.size']);
}])
->get();
return $tiers;
```